# Is there a Python library for easily writing zoomable UI's?

Tags: python, user-interface, opengl, gtk, cairo

My next work is going to be heavily focused on working with data that is best understood when organized on a two-dimensional zoomable plane or canvas, instead of using lists and property forms.

The library can be based on OpenGL, GTK+ or Cairo. It should allow me to:

- build widgets out of vector shapes and text (perhaps even SVG based?)
- arrange these widgets on a 2D plane
- catch widget-related events
- zoom deeply into a widget to reveal additional data
- arrange widgets in a tree
- animate widgets fluidly

It wouldn't hurt if it would also allow for some databinding or model/view concept.

Comment: Please put some results here, perhaps a small example script on pastebin, as soon as you have any progress! We would like very much to take a look at your results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org/) is perfect for you.

From the web site:

> Clutter is an open source software
>   library for creating fast, visually
>   rich and animated graphical user
>   interfaces.

Clutter is written in C, but it has great [Python bindings](http://clutter-project.org/sources/pyclutter/).

A very similar project is [Pigment](https://code.fluendo.com/pigment/trac):

> Pigment is a 3D scene graph library
>   designed to easily create rich
>   application user interfaces.

Comment: Worked with clutter before, and had a few issues with stability but I guess there is no way around it. Will also have a look at Pigment.

Answer (score 3):

Qt has this covered... check PyQt

Comment: I want to use GTK+ since it feels native on Ubuntu, the primary target platform.

Comment: Qt now (for a while) has had a QGtkStyle which makes it look completely native even on Gnome, as in other window managers.

See: http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2008/05/13/introducing-qgtkstyle/

Comment: Thanks for the hint, QGtkStyle solves another problem of mine. But now that I had a look at PyQt, I'm seriously put off. Certainly the library has everything, but I think that custom types, C++ signatures and signal handlers with type infos feel too weird to be considered. I stick to what I know ;)